# StreamWriter(Stream, Encoding) not working in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, streamwriter

I wanted to convert a file from UTF-16 to ANSI with Powershell and I encountered some behavior that I don't understand.

My (simplified) script is

```
$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1250)

$sr = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -Arg c:\utf16.txt
$sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter c:\new.txt, $false, $encoding

 while ($line = $sr.ReadLine()) {
    $sw.WriteLine($line)
 }

$sr.close()
$sw.Close()
```

And this is working fine, the output new.txt is in ANSI encoding
However, if I change

```
$sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter c:\new.txt, $false, $encoding
```

to

```
$sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter c:\new.txt, $encoding
```

the output new.txt is in UTF-8 encoding.
According to the [StreamWriter Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) documentation, this is also a valid StreamWriter Constructor to define the encoding.

What am I missing ?

Tom

Comment: `Get-Content -Path $Path -Encoding Unicode | Set-Content -Path C:\new.txt -Encoding ASCII`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing that `C:\new.txt` *still* is a **string**, not a **`Stream` object**. Meaning that you're invoking the [`StreamWriter(String, Boolean)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx) constructor, not the `StreamWriter(Stream, Encoding)` constructor. `$encoding` is [implicitly converted](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx) to boolean in this context. The former constructor creates a UTF-8 writer as documented:

> **Remarks**
>
> This constructor creates a StreamWriter with UTF-8 encoding without a Byte-Order Mark [...]